# Global variables in javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, web, global-variables, frontend, function-call

I have two functions in JavaScript. One is `change_BASE_ID()` and the other one is `Display_img(a,b)`.

`change_BASE_ID()` is called on mouseclick and internally calls `Display_img()`. On mouseover, `Display_img()` is called.

So `Display_img()` is used in two ways. There is a `base_id_mitali` variable in `change_BASE_ID()` which I want to be global. So even on mouseover when the `Display_img()` function is called independently, it should make use of the value of that variable.

If the onclick function was never clicked the value in `base_id_mitali` should be `01` or else if it was clicked it should be the one previously set ones.

```js
var base_id_mitali = "";

function change_BASE_ID(base_ID, cursor_ID) { // THIS IS WHEN MOUSE IS CLICKED
  //var curr_base_id = 'ch01ch01.png';
  var start_name = "ch";
  base_id_mitali = "01";
  var bsid = document.getElementById('image').src;
  //var bsidlen=bsid.charAt(bsid.length-6);
  var bid1 = bsid.charAt(bsid.length - 6);
  var bid2 = bsid.charAt(bsid.length - 5);
  document.getElementById("mitali").innerHTML = "trying to get base id ".concat(bid1).concat(bid2);
  base_id_mitali = concat(bid1).concat(bid2);

  var a = base_ID;
  var b = cursor_ID;

  var temp_res1 = start_name.concat(base_id_mitali);

  var temp_res2 = temp_res1.concat("ch");

  var temp_res3 = temp_res2.concat(b);

  var final = temp_res3.concat(".png");


  curr_base_id = final;

  document.getElementById('image').src = final;
  Display_img(base_ID, cursor_ID);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "clicked on ".concat(final);
  //setbaseid(base_id_mitali);

}

function Display_img(a, b) {

  var start_name = "ch";
  //document.getElementById("globalvar").innerHTML = "trying see global variable value ".concat(base_id_mitali);
  var temp_res1 = start_name.concat(a); //want to use the global variable instead of a

  var temp_res2 = temp_res1.concat("ch");

  var temp_res3 = temp_res2.concat(b);

  var final = temp_res3.concat(".png");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = final;


  document.getElementById('image').src = final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any initialization for the variable base_id_mitali in the code. Outside of your html code, initialize the variable on load using following code :

```
<script>
var base_id_mitali= "";
</script.
```

Now you can access this global variable .

Comment: not working. After i click. It should take the value of the variable which is set in change_BASE_ID function. Its not taking that value.

Comment: when onclick function is not clicked even once it should take value 01 if it is clicked it should take the value which is set in change_BASE_ID(base_ID,cursor_ID) function

Comment: Can you elaborate what value is being displayed in the first function .

Comment: It concatenates two id's to find name of the image to be displayed.